# Installing modules using sys.path.append in Python

Tags: python, installation, append

I was hoping for some advice.

My company has python version 3.5 IDLE.

My company is NOT a software company, i have started using it to automate some of my tasks.

The issue is that modules such as pandas or numpy is not installed and these modules will never be installed (no specific reason was given).

However i have discovered that .py files that are not installed or party of the standard library can be included using the following code:-

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Users\Joe\Test")
```

Test is a folder that contains various .py files.

I have pandas installed on my personal computer so I wanted to copy the pandas.py file from my personal computer into my work computer and put it in the Test folder shown above but i cannot seem to find pandas.py or numpy.py

My work computer is heavily restricted, i cannot access the c drive hence why i am trying to find an alternative method.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

I saw youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqvZ3vGoGs0&t=638s

Comment: `pandas` and `numpy` is not single file but folder with many files (modules) and it may have also code in C/C++ which may need to compile specially for 3.5 - bettter use `pip` to download module in `wheel` file (`.whl`) specially for Python 3.5 (but I'n not sure if it will no need C/C++ compiler).

Comment: on [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) you can find `pandas` and `numpy` precompiled for Python 3.5 on Windows (32bit and 64bit) but it seems old versions.

Comment: `pip install` has option `--user` to install modules in user's folder `%APPDATA%\Python` and it doesn't need to access Python's folder with modules.